# not able to implement paging successful in GridMVC.html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid

I am using GridMvc in view to populate document details. Below is the GridMvc code in view:

```
 <div style="width:5000px;">

        @Html.Grid(Model.allDocs).Columns(columns => 
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.SourceFileName).Titled("SourceFileName").Filterable(true).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false)
                            .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink(o.SourceFileName, "Download", "FormAdmin", new { Id = o.DataFileID }, new { target = "_blank" }).ToHtmlString());
                        columns.Add(c => c.ID).Titled("ID");
                        //columns.Add(c => c.SourceFileName).Titled("SourceFileName").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Createdate).Titled("CreateDate");
                        columns.Add(c => c.customerName).Titled("customerName");
                        columns.Add(c => c.CompanyName).Titled("CompanyName");


                    }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
    </div>
```

Below is the my code in controller:

```
public ActionResult DocDetails()
        {
            DocViewModel obj = new DocViewModel();


            obj.allDocs = new DocumentDetailsModel().GetDocumentViewModel();

            obj.ClientCodeLst = new DocumentDetailsModel().GetClientViewModel().ClientCodeLst;

            // obj.allSearch = new SearchParameters();
            obj.searchParam = new SearchParameters();

            return View(obj);
        }

     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DocDetails(DocViewModel b)
        {
            DocViewModel obj2 = new DocViewModel();




            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{

                obj2.allDocs = new DocumentDetailsModel().GetDocumentbySearch(b.searchParam.ID);

                obj2.ClientCodeLst = new DocumentDetailsModel().GetClientViewModel().ClientCodeLst;

                obj2.searchParam = new SearchParameters();

            //}
            return View(obj2);
        }
```

User selects specific value and populates Grid with records specific to those value.
After getting the value and populating grid with those data, when user click on paging for next record set of data then grid populates with all the default data but doesn't navigate to next set of data with specific value.

Can someone let me know where I miss understand concept?

Updated:

```
 public List<GetDocumentsParam> GetDocumentViewModel()
        {
            var fnResult1 = new List<GetDocumentsParam>();

            var edmx = new RepositoryEntities1();
            var getDocs = new GetDocumentsParam();



            return fnResult1 ;
        }

        public GetClientCodes GetClientViewModel()
        {
            var fnResult = new GetClientCodes();
            var edmx = new RepositoryEntities1();
            fnResult.ClientCodeLst = edmx.Clients
                                  .Select(s => s.ClientCode)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s, Value = s }).ToList();

            return fnResult;

        }

        public List<GetDocumentsParam> GetDocumentbySearch(DateTime date)
        {

            fnResult = new List<GetDocumentsParam>();
            //GetDocumentsParam objDoc = new GetDocumentsParam();
            var objDoc1 = (from c in db.DFiles
                               join b in db.BDatas
                               on c.ID equals b.ID
                               join d in db.Documents
                               on c.ID equals d.ID
                               where d.CreateDate == date
                               select new GetDocumentsParam
                               {
                                   ID = c.ID,
                                   SourceFileName = c.SourceFileName,
                                   Createdate = c.CreateDate,
CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                                                                      ClientCode = c.ClientCode


                               });
            fnResult = objDoc1.ToList();
           // fnResult = queryResults;
            return fnResult;
        }

public class DocViewModel
    {

        public List<GetDocumentsParam> allDocs { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> ClientCodeLst { get; set; }

        public SearchParameters searchParam { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your ViewModel codes? It can help to see what is wrong maybe.

Comment: I have added ViewModel code. please check and help me!!